# Acessing the properties from object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm getting some data remotely from a url, and i could access it with success, but when i try to get the properties from the object it gives me a error, cant figure out whats the problem.

Code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://domain.com:8000/api/information?limit=100');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((request.readyState===4) && (request.status===200)) {
        var ob = request.responseText;
        console.log(ob.name);
        //document.writeln(request.responseText);
    }
}
request.send();
```

Example output data:
{"id":"123","name":"blabla","price":346,"date":"31-01-2015"}

Error: undefined

Comment: what does `console.log(ob);` show?

Comment: Is `responseText` parsed?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend for this approach but for your problem this is a workaround:

```
var res = request.responseText;
res = res.replace(/"/g,'\\"'); //replacing quotes
res = res.replace(/}{/g,'},{'); //separating object string by comma
res = "["+res+"]";
var data = JSON.parse(res); //parsing data
```

Comment: I already did it and gave me a error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: Can you add the data that is returned from the api or jsFiddle link to the code.

Comment: Im working locally, but the data that is returned is like this: http://pastebin.com/VwegrjBj

Comment: @MônicaR. U mean to say `console.log(request.responseText)` gives you that output that is shown in link you have shared? From what I see, it should give you an array right? So you got to iterate over that response array, JSON.parse() each item while iterating and then fetch `.name` property value.

Comment: A quick way to convert the string representation of a JavaScript object is to eval it with brackets: var ob=eval('('+request.responseText+')');